# Problema al compilar VueJs 2 con Bootstrap 4 (Solo CSS)

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4

Sucede que solo quiero usar Bootstrap para darle estilo a mi aplicación, pero al momento de correrla me sale el siguiente error

```
 ERROR  Failed to compile with 2 errors                                                                                                                13:10:24
These dependencies were not found:

* jquery in ./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js
* popper.js in ./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js
```

Quiero saber como puedo hacer que deje de necesitar esas dos dependencias y solo ocupe el CSS

mi Main.js esta asi

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import store from './store'
import 'bootstrap'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

Answer (score 1):

Acabo de resolverlo, resulta que estaba haciendo la importación mal, lo unico que habia que cambiar era en el `main.js`

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import store from './store'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css //De esta forma solo se carga la parte del CSS
Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

Solo tenia que dejar el paquete de css